# Javascript jQuery not executing after .is(":checkbox") check?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a click event that loops through the items of an html table and saves them to an array.  I am attempting to identify if the passed value is a checkbox which seems to be working correctly.  However when I add the check the code won't fully execute after it hits the check?  (The ajax code is never reached.)  Am I missing something here? Searching other posts one suggestion was to move the declaration of my checked variable outside the each statement which I did.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var valueArray = [];
    var headers = [];
    var dataToSend;
    var checked = null;
    var arrayItem = {};
    $('#table th').each(function (index, item) {
        headers[index] = $(item).html();
    });
    $('#table tr').has('td').each(function () {
        $('td', $(this)).each(function (index, item) {
            arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();


            checked = $(arrayItem[headers[index]]).is(":checkbox");  

        });
        valueArray.push(arrayItem);
        dataToSend = JSON.stringify(valueArray);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveTable", "Home")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataToSend,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    });
  });
```

Comment: You are storing HTML string, that won't work... Test on the actual object like $(item).is(":checkbox"). To fully help you, we'd need a bit of HTML...

Comment: What are you using `checked` for?

Comment: Ultimately I want to get the value of the checkbox so I can pass it back to my SaveTable controller and manipulate the data there based on that.  I would think that I first need to find out if the element is even a checkbox to begin with.

Comment: If I comment out the "checked" check then the execution doesn't stop is my error must be there.  Is it possible to do a checkbox check on $(item).html()?